# Render is completely transparent

Tags: uv

I've checked the active camera, there's nothing in the sequence editor, I've tried everything and cannot figure out what I broke.

I literally just want it to render out how it looks in the viewport a Smoking crashed spaceship against a green screen. But for some reason, the render is blank, and then also it puts the video clip from the motion track on it too, which I don't want it to do either but that's a different issue.

Viewport:
[image: Viewport render]
Node tree:
[image]
Notice how the initial render is completely blank...?

Comment: The rederlayers seem misconfigured to me, the two layers they are set to render render completely blank in the viewport. Is that intentional?

Comment: in the render layer you have not included the right scene layers just check them and that's it

Comment: @Chebhou That is almost exactly what I said . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise would like to answer it ?

Comment: @Chebhou Sure, I just like to double check with the OP generally.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise and there you go ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the layers you have set your *Render Layers* to are completely blank in front of the camera. You need to add the correct layers in your *Render Layers* settings.

[image]
[image]

The reason this was rendering in the viewport, is you had all of the layers selected to display in your viewport, while those layers were not enabled in the final render.

[image: Viewport layers]

You may want to disable the compositing stage to get ride of the video overlay :

[image]

to keep the compositing and just eliminate the video overlay change the compositing nodes as this :

[image]

Comment: disabling the composting will solve the video overlay

Comment: True. I forgot to include that. The OP asked about why it rendered as transparent so that is what I answered :/